# I'm very new to python and pygame and am having trouble understanding this error message

Tags: pygame

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((640,360),0,32)
pygame.display.set_caption("My game.")

black = [0,0,0]
white = [255,255,255]

img = pygame.image.load("images/bg.jpg").convert_aplpha() # This is where I get the error.
```

The error I am getting is `img = pygame.image.load("images/bg.jpg").convert_aplpha()
AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'convert_aplpha'`
Please, what does this mean and how may I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`convert_aplpha()` is not a function, or an attribute at all. Perhaps you meant `convert_alpha()`?

```
# wrong
img = pygame.image.load("images/bg.jpg").convert_aplpha()
# right
img = pygame.image.load("images/bg.jpg").convert_alpha()
```

Comment: Not only is it not a function, but it's not an attribute either.  The name `convert_aplpha` doesn't exist at all as a member of the return type of `load()`.

Comment: Yes, you're both right. I just seemed to have made a symple typo. Thanks.